# Mongodb joining 2 collections on more than 1 field

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 collections shopping_cart & product as below. I want to join them and calculate price of each item and then total price of the cart.

shopping_cart:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62f4dfe964cb83eae07634f4"),
    "user" : ObjectId("62e4ef9aa7bae2d09973f9a0"),
    "shopping_cart_items" : [
        {
            "product_id" : ObjectId("62f38262a223a7e04f95f459"),
            "option_id" : ObjectId("62f382eea223a7e04f95f45a"),
            "quantity" : NumberInt(3)
        },
        {
            "product_id" : ObjectId("62f38262a223a7e04f95f459"),
            "option_id" : ObjectId("62f382eea223a7e04f95f45b"),
            "quantity" : NumberInt(1)
        }
    ]
}
```

product:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62f38262a223a7e04f95f459"),
    "product_options" : [
        {
            "options_id" : ObjectId("62f382eea223a7e04f95f45a"),
            "selling_price" : NumberInt(1500)
        },
        {
            "options_id" : ObjectId("62f382eea223a7e04f95f45b"),
            "selling_price" : NumberInt(2250)
        },
        {
            "options_id" : ObjectId("62f382eea223a7e04f95f45c"),
            "selling_price" : NumberInt(3000)            
         }
    ]
}
```

Expectation:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62f4dfe964cb83eae07634f4"),
    "user" : ObjectId("62e4ef9aa7bae2d09973f9a0"),
    "shopping_cart_items" : {
        "product_id" : ObjectId("62f38262a223a7e04f95f459"),
        "option_id" : ObjectId("62f382eea223a7e04f95f45a"),
        "quantity" : NumberInt(3),
        "price":NumberInt(4500) //shopping_cart_items.quantity * product_options.selling_price
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62f4dfe964cb83eae07634f4"),
    "user" : ObjectId("62e4ef9aa7bae2d09973f9a0"),
    "shopping_cart_items" : {
        "product_id" : ObjectId("62f38262a223a7e04f95f459"),
        "option_id" : ObjectId("62f382eea223a7e04f95f45b"),
        "quantity" : NumberInt(5)
        "price":NumberInt(2250) //shopping_cart_items.quantity * product_options.selling_price

    }
}
```

And how can I add both products in total price?

Answer (score 1):

To join 2 mongodb collections (in the aggregation pipeline), you can use the `lookup` stage, which has two different syntax ([doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)):

- simple syntax: to just join two collections on a field:

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

- more advanced: to implement custom condition and apply some sub-queries on the joined collection

```
{
   $lookup:
      {
         from: <joined collection>,
         let: { <var_1>: <expression>, …, <var_n>: <expression> },
         pipeline: [ <pipeline to run on joined collection> ],
         as: <output array field>
      }
}
```

For you problem, you need first to expand `shopping_cart_items` array in the `shopping_cart` collection, then use the second syntax for `lookup` to expand `product_options` in the `product` collection and join it to the first one:

```
shopping_cart.aggregate([
   { $unwind: "shopping_cart_items" },
   {
      $lookup:
         {
           from: "product",
           let: { cart_product_id: "$shopping_cart_items.product_id", cart_option_id: "$shopping_cart_items.option_id" },
           pipeline: [
              { $unwind: "product_options" },
              { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$_id",  "$$inventory_id" ] },
                         { $eq: [ "$product_options.options_id", "$$cart_option_id" ] }
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              }
           ],
           as: "shopping_cart_items"
         }
    }
])
```

This will give an array of all matched items (probably of one item), you can change the result structure and expand the array by adding more stages to this pipeline.

Comment: Thanks  @Hussein Awala
I was missing the inner unwind.. thanks again !